# How do I wrap x & y axis in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So in my GameScene I have these lines in the beginning of func didMoveToView

```
    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = border
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

It works fine for preventing my player from going outside the screen; However, I want my player, or anything else in the scene, to go to the other side of the screen when touching the border. In other words: If i kept going right i would keep going right until i hit the border then my player would appear from the left border and continue going right in an endless loop.

Same goes for y axis.

How is this possible in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if player.position.x + player.size.width / 2 > size.width {
    player.position.x = -player.size.width 
}
else if player.position.x + player.size.width / 2 < 0 {
    player.position.x = size.width + player.size.width / 2
```

Same logic for Y axis.

Comment: Thank You!! Although I edited it a bit to get it to work perfectly. I will post the details in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is interested to reproduce this, I had to delete the following code:

```
let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
border.friction = 0
self.physicsBody = border
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Then, in touchesMoved I added:

```
    if Player.position.x + Player.size.width / 16 > size.width {
        Player.position.x = Player.size.width / 16

    }
    else if Player.position.x + Player.size.width / 16 < 0 {
        Player.position.x = size.width - Player.size.width / 16

    }
```

for the x axis. & the same can be done for the Y axis except we will change the x to y & the width to height.